# Django - Why are variables declared in Model Classes Static

Tags: python, django

I have been reading and working with Django for a bit now. One of the things that I am still confused with is why the model classes that we create in Django are made up of static variables and not member variables. For instance

```
class Album(models.Model):
    artist = models.CharField(max_length=128, unique=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=128, unique=True)
    genre = models.CharField(max_length=128, unique=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name
```

I read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68645/static-class-variables-in-python) page here which explains static and instance variables in python however i am still confused as to why Django wants the field variables in models be static ?

Comment: There is an excellent write up on how models are created in Pro Django, chapter 3 (Models) by Marty Alchin, Apress

Answer (score 11):

Django uses a [metaclass](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#customizing-class-creation) to create the model class. Just as a class's `__init__()` method creates a new instance, the metaclass's `__new__()` method creates the class itself. All variables, functions, properties, etc. defined in the class body are passed to the `__new__()` function. Strictly speaking, just defining a variable in the class body does not create a static/class variable -- only when the `__new__()` function receives the variable and sets it on the class, will it be a class/static variable.

Django overrides this behavior when it comes to fields and the special `Meta` inner class, by providing a custom `__new__()` method. The options in the inner `Meta` class are converted to an `Options` instance, and that instance is stored as `Model._meta` rather than `Model.Meta`. Similarly, any fields you define are stored in `Model._meta.fields` rather than as class/static variables.

You will notice that in your example, the class `Album` does not have a `artist` attribute: `Album.artist` will simply raise an `AttributeError`. This is because the metaclass moves the field from the class to `Album._meta.fields`. Instances of `Album` do have an `artists` attribute, but *this is not the field*. Instead, it's the database value related to the field. The `__init__` method of a model uses `self._meta.fields` to populate any attributes with either the value that is passed to `__init__`, or with the default value, to assure that the instance variable exists.

Only class variables are passed to the `__new__` method. If you were to define a field as an instance variable inside `__init__`, the field would never be passed to `Model._meta.fields`, and Django simply doesn't know about the field. You will be able to access `Album.artist`, but this will be the actual field instance, not the related database value. Basically you would be missing the magic that makes a model into a model.